# error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') - Nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nodemailer, next.js13

I'm having issue in the title with my post API endpoint created within Nextjs.

My endpoint is for a form submission, where I take the inputs and forward them to my email. My current code sends the email and I receive it just fine on my email, HOWEVER it keeps returning the error in the title every time I make the request.

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server"
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  const formData = await request.formData()

  const emailValue = formData.get("email")
  const messageValue = formData.get("message")
  const numberValue = formData.get("phone_number")

  if (!messageValue || !numberValue || !emailValue) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "please fill all required fields!" }, { status: 400 })
  }

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  })

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${emailValue}`,
    to: `${process.env.EMAIL}`,
    subject: `Message from contact me page from ${numberValue} - ${emailValue} `,
    text: `${messageValue}`,
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: `${err}` }, { status: 500 })
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Email sent successfully!" }, { status: 200 })
  })
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I read in one thread about executing the NextResponse in a return statement, and even that didn't work.

The error I'm getting

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:261:61)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: The error doesn't appear to come directly from this code. Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace

Comment: May the error is with the usage of `NextResponse` may try replacing it with `response.send()` and check

Comment: What would the type of `response` be ? It's NextResponse in my code and it doesn't have a send method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51130).

Your last two `return NextResponse...` calls are within the `transporter.sendMail()` callback so they won't return from the `POST()` function.

Take advantage of [Nodemailer's ability to return a promise](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail) instead of using callbacks...

> If callback argument is not set then the method returns a Promise object.

```js
try {
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  return NextResponse.json(
    { message: "Email sent successfully!" },
    { status: 200 },
  );
} catch (err) {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: err.toString() }, { status: 500 });
}
```

---

The alternative is to promis-ify the Nodemailer callback though IMO it's not nearly as clean

```js
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => {
    const status = err ? 500 : 200;
    const message = err?.toString() ?? "Email sent successfully!";
    resolve(NextResponse.json({ message }, { status }));
  });
});
```

Comment: I really like the promis-ified approach though